# Bind Ember.select to values loaded from the server

Tags: ember.js, ember.select

I have a select view like this:

```
App.sectors = ["Alpinism", "Climbing", "Kayaking];

{{view Ember.Select contentBinding="App.sectors"}}
```

Now instead of a vector of fixed values, i would like to have the select view populated with values coming from the server; in other words i would like to do something like:

```
App.sectors = function() {
    return this.store.find('sector');
}
```

but this doesn't work since Ember says i have to pass a vector to contentBinding and not a function...

(i have the sector model defined:

```
App.Sector = DS.Model.extend({
    description: DS.attr('string')
});
```

and my restful server answers correctly to the EmberData get request on 'domain/sectors')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a computed property on the controller in scope and return your real data from there.

```
App.IndexController = Em.Controller.extend({
  colors: function(){
    return this.get('store').find('color');
  }.property()
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/199/edit

Comment: Can you also tell me how to set the default selected value of the Ember Select View?